# Adjusting gif framerate in GIMP 2

Tags: gimp, gif

How can I open a gif with GIMP and adjust the framerate?

When I try to reexport it, the option for this is whited out (see screenshot below):

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just click on the `As Animation` checkbox - it will enable the animation options (and actually save an animation, instead of a flatenned GIF image)

That is your answer -  but taking the opportunity of the question repeat an information that is somewhat hard to find or understand: if you  want to customize the frame duration of any specific layer, it is possible to do that by putting a special sequence in the given layer's name within GIMP: on its name, include the frame duration in milliseconds, post fixed by "ms". That is, if you want the last (topmost in GIMP) frame to stay on the screen for 3 seconds, just add `(3000ms)`  as part of its name. (Add the parenthesis as well - they are not needed for gif export, but other plug-ins may require them).

Comment: Thank you. Note also that it is daunting to change the delay for every frame individually to a consisten new value, but note that instead you can leave them all as is, and just click "export" and then check the option "Use delay entered above for all frames"